# Pandas slice row by index list for column

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
                           county reporting_code
0           other locality rate %           code
1           New York State only 4           0021
2                        Albany 8           0181
3                   Allegany 81/2           0221
```

I would like it to be:

```
                           county reporting_code  rate
0           other locality rate %           code   %
1           New York State only 4           0021   4
2                        Albany 8           0181   8
3                   Allegany 81/2           0221   81/2
```

I need to extract the numbers in the county column into a new column and convert them to decimals. I get the index of the last space in the county column:

```
indx = (df0['county'].str.rindex(' '))
```

indx returns:

```
0     19
1     19
2      6
3      8
```

I then try:

```
df0['rate'] = df0['county'].str.slice(start=indx)
```

df0 then returns:

```
                           county reporting_code  rate
0           other locality rate %           code   NaN
1           New York State only 4           0021   NaN
2                        Albany 8           0181   NaN
3                   Allegany 81/2           0221   NaN
```

I think pandas slice tries to apply the same each index in the list for each row. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `rsplit`

```
df0['rate'] = df0['county'].str.rsplit(' ', n = 1).str[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Forgot about the maxsplit parameter on the split function.